# configure multiple ip on same vlan on centos 7 machine

Tags: centos, networking, systemd, vlan

My existing network file looks like below

`# cat ifcfg-ens1.200
DEVICE=ens1.200
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.16.2.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=172.16.2.0
VLAN=yes`

How to setup assign another ip address inside same vlan, below is what i tried but it gave errors

```
# cat ifcfg-ens1:1.200
DEVICE=ens1:1.200
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.16.1.253
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=172.16.1.0
VLAN=yes
```

Error msg:-

```
service network restart
Restarting network (via systemctl):  Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: your error is saying to run `systemctl status network.service` or `journalctl -xe` for details on why it failed, you should check that and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Centimane i couldnt find any clue in journalctl -xe about the error, the error was due to incorrect filenaming

Answer (score 1):

Actually the filename i was using was culprit below is what worked

```
network-scripts]$ cat ifcfg-ens1.200:1

DEVICE='ens1.200:1'
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=172.16.2.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=172.16.2.0
VLAN=yes
```

systemctl restart network #after changing file